# load img failed in HTML5 application cache

Tags: javascript, html, caching

This is my cache manifest:
    CACHE MANIFEST

```
# VERSION 1.4

# 直接缓存的文件
CACHE:
account.html
index.html
performance.html
cashier.html
login.html
register.html
assets/css/account.css
assets/css/editProduct.css

# 需要在线的文件
NETWORK:

# 替代方案
FALLBACK:
```

When loading imgs in index.html(from cache),the browser doesn't send img request!

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTML5's caching (interesting!), but don't the image resource's caching headers have to be taken in account for this, too?

Comment: The browser will cache images automatically based on the unique URL. A way around this is to append a random number to the end of the image URL.  <url>/image.gif?12345

Comment: @cgatian I've tried,the browser still doesn't send img request!But putting * at the NETWORK fixed it.I don't why.